# Count total customer_id's not partitioned by column

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to calculate the total number of customers without adding an additional subquery. The count should be partitioned by country but rather by the month_ column.

EDIT:
I updated the query to use GROUPING SETS

Current query:

```
select date_trunc('month',date_) as month_,
country,
count(distinct customer_id) as total_customers 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
   (date_trunc('month',date_), country),
   (date_trunc('month',date_))
from table_a
```

Current output

```
month_        country  total_customers_per_country   
2020-01-01    US       320                          
2020-01-01    GB       360                           
2020-01-01             680
2020-02-01    US       345                          
2020-02-01    GB       387
2020-02-01             732
```

Desired output:

```
month_        country  total_customers_per_country   total_customers
2020-01-01    US       320                           680
2020-01-01    GB       360                           680
2020-02-01    US       345                           732
2020-02-01    GB       387                           732
```

Comment: Read on the usage of `GROUP BY ROLLUP` in the docs of the [SELECT](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) page.

Comment: I ended up using GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (month_, country),
    (month_) 
)                                                                                                                                                But I was wondering how I could get the rows where the country field is null as its own column

Comment: A minimal set of input data, with desired output would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the version of sql server you are using but you are likely looking for "window" functions.

I believe something along the lines of the following will give you the result you are looking for:

```
select date_trunc('month',date_) as month_,
country,
count(distinct customer_id) as total_customers_by_country,
count(distinct customer_id) OVER (partition by date_trunc('month',date_)) as total_customers
from table_a
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I tried that already but i get the following error:  count(distinct customer_id) OVER partition by (date_trunc('month,date_)) as total_customers must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0):

You can perform subquery to group by month-country pair and then use `sum` over window partitioned by month:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, date, country) AS (
    VALUES (1, date '2020-01-01', 'US'),
        (2, date '2020-01-01', 'US'),
        (1, date '2020-01-01', 'GB'),
        (3, date '2020-01-02', 'US'),
        (1, date '2020-01-02', 'GB'),
        (1, date '2020-02-01', 'US')
) 

--query
select *,
    sum(total_customers_per_country) over (partition by month) total_customers
from (
        select date_trunc('month', date) as month,
            country,
            count(distinct id) total_customers_per_country   
        from dataset
        group by 1, country
    )
order by month, country desc
```

Output:

| month | country | total_customers_per_country | total_customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | US | 3 | 4 |
| 2020-01-01 | GB | 1 | 4 |
| 2020-02-01 | US | 1 | 1 |